# What is the difference of extension and module in opencart?

Tags: opencart

I am new to opencart, and I am confused about the terminology between extension and module in opencart, could anyone explain to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Extensions**: are used to give the additional functionality to the CMS 
  In Opencart, You have the extensions like payment, modules, totals etc.

**Modules** : this is the special type of extensions which is used to show the information at the front store or adding the functionality that cannot fit into other extensions types
read this article for more information 
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/opencart/admin-tools/what-are-opencart-extensions-and-modules

For Example:
 Payment extensions : All payment extension have only one work to process the payment so it is further categorized as payment extensions.
and second thing all payment gateways should be list at checkout page so Opencart makes a special category for them same for total extensions

Modules: We cannot say what one module can do If you want to show the user just welcome message you can make the module for it and add it to any layout

Answer (score 3):

**Modules**: blocks of HTML that have their own config in Extensions > Modules and can be applied to Layout Templates to appear on the left/right/top/bottom of the page. The category left nav is a module.

**Extensions**: zip files containing an /upload folder which contains files to be uploaded to the web root of your site and can include, new files, new themes, new modules and vQmods. Extensions can add pretty much any functionality to the store and often have an area in the admin for settings and often but not always make changes to the front-end of the store.

More info here:
http://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-modules-and-extensions-in-opencar/

Answer (score 1):

Extensions are add-on programs that provide extra functionality to your website.

Modules are boxes of information on your site that help the customer make their purchase. These do not provide extra functionality to your website but are intended to display information. Some modules are included by default, such as Account, Affiliate, Bestsellers, Featured, Specials, etc.

I hope this helps, look at this link for some more [extensions](http://www.magikcommerce.com/opencart/extensions/).

Answer (score 0):

Module is extention. Payment and Shiping and other is extentions to.

Answer (score -3):

The contrast amongst modules and augmentations in Opencart are:

Modules: A more lightweight and adaptable expansion utilized for page rendering is a module. Modules are utilized for little bits of the page that are by and large less perplexing and ready to be seen crosswise over various segments. Some of the time modules are connected to a segment, for example, the centre most recent news module.

Augmentations: Components, dialects, modules, module and formats are altogether known as Extensions.

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).